# java.net.ConnectException: Your endpoint configuration is wrong;

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am running word count program from my windows machine on hadoop cluster which is setup on remote linux machine.
Program is running successfully and I am getting output but I am getting following exception and my waitForCompletion(true) is not returning true.

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Your endpoint configuration is wrong; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnsetHostnameOrPort
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:328)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.isComplete(Job.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1629)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1591)
    at practiceHadoop.WordCount$1.run(WordCount.java:60)
    at practiceHadoop.WordCount$1.run(WordCount.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1682)
    at practiceHadoop.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Your endpoint configuration is wrong; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnsetHostnameOrPort
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:831)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:751)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getJobReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getJobReport(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:326)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1552)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1383)
    ... 26 more
```

My MapReduce Program which I run on eclipse (windows)

```
  UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("admin");
    ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

      public Void run() throws Exception {
        try {
          Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

          configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "192.168.33.75:50001"); // see step 3
          configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
          configuration.set("yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env",
              "HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/admin/hadoop-3.1.0");
          configuration.set("mapreduce.map.env", "HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/admin/hadoop-3.1.0");
          configuration.set("mapreduce.reduce.env", "HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/admin/hadoop-3.1.0");
          configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.33.75:54310"); // see step 2
          configuration.set("mapreduce.app-submission.cross-platform", "true");
          configuration.set("mapred.remote.os", "Linux");
          configuration.set("yarn.application.classpath",
              "{{HADOOP_CONF_DIR}},{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/*,{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,"
                  + " {{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,{{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,"
                  + "{{HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,{{HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME}}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,"
                  + "{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/*,{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*");


          configuration.set("mlv_construct", "min");
          configuration.set("column_name", "TotalCost");

          Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration);
          job.setJar("C:\\Users\\gauravp\\Desktop\\WordCountProgam.jar");
          job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class); // use this when uploaded the Jar to the server and
                                              // running the job directly and locally on the server
          job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
          job.setMapperClass(MapForWordCount.class);
          job.setReducerClass(ReduceForWordCount.class);

          Path input = new Path("/user/admin/wordCountInput.txt");
          Path output = new Path("/user/admin/output");
          FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);
          fs.delete(output);
          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);


           if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
           System.out.println("Job done...");
           }
```

One more observation :
My connection from windows machine to remote linux machine ports (54310 and 50001) vanish after some time.

- [HDFS port connection status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqaJf.png)
- [yarn port connection status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvUF7.png)

I am stuck here from last 5 days. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I can see, your hadoop configuration is not set-up correctly. Because it is unable to resolve the hostname. So, please check the hadoop configurations

Comment: @Abhinav : Thanks. But same program is running successfully if I run it on linux machine locally.

Comment: That is why I am asking how exactly are you trying to run the query from other OS

Comment: added the client program as well.

Comment: did you change memory configuration in mapred-default.xml recently ?

Answer (score 5):

Check if your ResourceManager and NodeManager services are up and running using jps command. In my case only NameNode and DataNode services were up and above were not running. So when running a INSERT query on Hive, when it tried to run map reduce job it was failing with above error.
Starting yarn services mentioned above fixed the issue for me.